# My event.preventDefault() doesn't stop the href from happening

Tags: javascript, href, preventdefault

I have a problem with Javascript, I made an image with areas and I wanted something to happen when one of the area is clicked.

At first, when I clicked, the event happened and the page seemed to "reload" immediatly. After a little research, I tried to add `event.preventDefault()` because I think the `href=""` was the problem, and putting `href="404"` confirmed it. But the `event.preventDefault()` does not stop the href from happening.

I tried this :

```
document.getElementsByClassName("D").onclick = function () {myFunction()}; function () {myFunction2()};

function myFunction(){
stopImmediatePropagation() ;
event.preventDefault();
}

function myFunction2() {
$('.a1').addClass('visible');
$('.a1').removeClass('dissimule');

}
```

and

```
document.getElementsByClassName("D").onclick = function () {myFunction()};

function myFunction(){
event.preventDefault();
$('.dissimule').addClass('visible');
$('.dissimule').removeClass('dissimule');
}
```

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName` return a collection.I dont think `document.getElementsByClassName("D").onclick` will work

Comment: And also you are not receving your event.

Comment: You're not passing in `event` into your function - so `preventDefault()` won't work as `event` will be null.

Comment: Where is your `event` variable being defined? It's definitely not in your code